# How to generate empty (no sound) audio file with AVAudioFile?

Tags: ios, swift, macos, audio

I searched a lot on the Internet but found no luck. I tried with below code, it generate file but it has zero duration and tried to play with system audio player, it did not open the file. My purpose is to generate empty(silent audio) file with **AVAudioFile** to put in between another

```
 import Foundation
 import AVFoundation

 let filename = FileManager.default.urls(for: .downloadsDirectory, in:  .userDomainMask).first!.appendingPathComponent("testing.wav")
 let format = AVAudioFormat(commonFormat: .pcmFormatFloat32, sampleRate: 44100, channels: 1,     interleaved: false)!
 let f = try? AVAudioFile(forWriting:filename, settings: format.settings)
 let b = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: format, frameCapacity:      AVAudioFrameCount(180*format.sampleRate))!

//Even insert zeros in first channel, but no results
//for i in 0..<Int(b.frameCapacity){
// b.floatChannelData![0][i] = 0.0
//}

 b.frameLength = b.frameCapacity

try! f!.write(from: b)
print("done")
```

[**output Audio file details**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Ecsd.png)

Comment: Have you tried to fill the AudioBufferList with buffers of of the right size with data set to nil ?

Comment: Have you looked at [AVMutableComposition](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avmutablecomposition)

Comment: Thanks guys for commenting. Actually problem is that not closing **AVAudioFile**, but there is no such method to close the file, so it must be explicitly set NIL or put in some scope, so as scope execution ended then the file will be automatically closed. In my case I was executing code in playground,  so just putting in function it works like charm and keep in mind that **AVAudioFile** instance var should be local